# Define the concepts of a convergent series and an absolutely convergent series.

Tags: power-series

Define the concepts of a convergent series and an absolutely convergent series. For which $a ∈  \mathbb R$ number

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^a}}$$

on is convergent, and for which it converges absolutely?

I want to use d'Alebert for this. And check this for periods for the $a$.

1) $a\in (0,1)$

2) $a\in (1,\infty)$

3) $a=0$

4) $a\in (-1,0)$

5) $a\in (-\infty,-1)$

I stared calculated $lim_{x\to \infty}{{\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}}}$

$lim_(x\to \infty){\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^a}}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^a}}}=lim_(x\to \infty){\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^a}}{\frac{n^a}{(-1)^{n}}}=-lim_(x\to \infty){\frac{n^a}{(n+1)^a}}$

This is for a convergent series. Equation for a absolute series will be without $-$.
This place where I'm stuck. What is next step?

Comment: We can't apply ratio test for alternating series since we need that the terms are with constant sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left|\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^a}\right|}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^a}}$$

converges, by [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), if and only if $a>1$ and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^a}}$$

converges by [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) for $a>0$ and diverges otherwise since $a_n \not \to 0$.